# Alternateive SQL Query for a Badly-Designed Oracle Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am pulling data from a legacy table (that I did not design) to convert that data for use in a different application.  Here is the truncated table design:

```
-- Create table
create table order
(
  insert_timestamp   TIMESTAMP(6) default systimestamp not null,
  numeric_identity   NUMBER not null,
  my_data            VARCHAR2(100) not null
)

-- Create/Recreate primary, unique and foreign key constraints 
alter table order
  add constraint order_pk primary key (numeric_identity, insert_timestamp);
```

The idea behind this original structure was that the numeric_identity identified a particular customer.  The most current order would be the one with the newest insert timestamp value for the given customer's numeric identity.  In this particular case, there are no instances where more than one row has the same insert_timestamp value and numeric_identity value.

I'm tasked with retrieving this legacy data for conversion.  I wrote the following query to pull back the latest, unique records, as older records need not be converted:

```
select * from order t where t.insert_timestamp = 
  (select max(w.insert_timestamp) from order 
  where t.numeric_identity = w.numeric_identity);
```

This pulls back the expected dataset, but could fail if there somehow were more than one row with the same insert_timestamp and numeric_identity.  Is there a better query than what I've written to pull back unique records in a table designed in this fashion?

Comment: but numeric_identity and the timestamp are a primary key, they cannot have duplicates or you have way more problems than a query...

Comment: In this exact scenario, yes, the primary key saves me.  This table design is not unique in the schema I'm working with, though.  And this is one of the few tables with a primary key constraint.  Others exist without the constraint and have not caused problems through sheer dumb luck.  Again, this was not my design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to write this query:

```
select *
  from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by numeric_identity order by insert_timestamp desc) rn
          from order t)
 where rn = 1
```

Also, you can't get situation when one row has the same `insert_timestamp` and `numeric_identity`, because you have primary key on these two columns.

Comment: No, I understand for this exact scenario that it's impossible with the primary key constraint.  Unfortunately, this table design is not unique in this schema. and this is one of the few tables designed in this manner that has a primary key constraint.